# Is it legal to new-allocate a pointer to function?

Tags: c++

Pointers to functions are not plain data pointers as they cannot be stored in a void* pointer. 
Nonetheless, it seems that I can store the copy of a function-pointer in dynamic memory
(in gcc and clang) like in the code below. Is such a code legal according to the C++ Standard, 
or maybe this is some sort of compiler extension?

Moreover, the resulting pointer to function-pointer behaves as a plain data pointer: I can 
store it in void* and retrieve it from void* by static_cast. Is this behavior guranteed by the Standard?

```
int main()
{
  extern void fcn();
  void (*fcnPtr)() = &fcn;
  void (**ptrToFcnPtr)() = nullptr;

  //Make the copy of fcnPtr on the heap:
  ptrToFcnPtr = new decltype(fcnPtr)(fcnPtr);
  //Call the pointed-to function : 
  (**ptrToFcnPtr)();

  //Save the pointer in void* :
  void *ptr = ptrToFcnPtr;
  //retrieve the original ptr: 
  auto myPtr = static_cast< void(**)() > (ptr) ; 
  //free memory:
  delete ptrToFcnPtr ;

}
```

Comment: Please don't use raw funciton pointers. Use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead.

Comment: You don't need the `new` to cast to `void*`. `void* ptr = &fcnPtr;` works just as well, since `fcnPtr` is an object, not a function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `std::function` is a type-erased container for storing an arbitrary callable, not really a replacement for function pointers…

Comment: you are not dynamically creating a function, but you are dynamically creating a pointer. Basically thats what the answer says also, but I am not sure if that is your misunderstanding...

Comment: What is the *real* and *underlying* problem you need to solve? Why do you need all these pointer? What are you using them for?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was wondering how std::function is implemented. My implementation stores the address of heap-allocated copy of the functor in void* pointer, where functor in question may be a fucntion-pointer (or something else).

Comment: (@Someprogrammerdude) Please don't blindly use/recommend `std::function`. It's great for its ability to store "polymorphic" functions (i.e. anything with the right signature, even if it contains state as in the case of some lambdas), but that also adds overhead that may not be needed. A pointer to a function is POD. A `std::function` is not.

Comment: @Matthew To be fair, Adrian is asking about dynamically allocating the pointer to function and pointing to it with a type-erasing `void*`, so in the context of this question `std::function` seems to be exactly what they were looking for. I do agree that SPD's general dismissal of function pointers is unsound.

Comment: If you incorrectly allocate pointers, the Pointer Police will get you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While function pointers are not object pointers, "pointer to function of some type" is still an object type [[basic.types]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#8). Thus, function pointers are themselves objects, just the thing they point to is not.

Thus, you sure can create an object of function pointer type via a new expression…

Answer (score 9):

> as they (function pointers) cannot be stored in a void* pointer.

Actually, storing a function pointer as a `void*` is conditionally supported. This means that either it can or cannot be stored depending on the language implementation. If the language implementation supports dynamic loading, then converting function pointer in `void*` probably is supported. GCC, Clang and MSVC all support this:

```
reinterpret_cast<void*>(&function);
```

> Is it legal to new-allocate a pointer to function?

Sure. All pointers, including function pointers, are objects and all objects can be allocated dynamically.

> Moreover, the resulting pointer to function-pointer behaves as a plain data pointer

Function pointer is an object. Pointer to a function pointer not only "behaves as", but **is** a pointer to an object.

> I can store it in void* and retrieve it from void* by static_cast. Is this behavior guranteed by the Standard?

Conversion between pointer to void and pointer to object is allowed, yes. And round-trip conversion is guaranteed to yield the original pointer.

Comment: Thanks. But then to convert function-pointer to void* (or the other way around) I need to use reinterpret_cast, right?

Comment: @Adrian Yes. I added an example.

Comment: If anybody wants an exception to probably: dos medium memory model + overlays. Function pointers are larger than data pointers in medium model, and overlays can be used to achieve plugins if you try hard enough.